# How can you find collapsed elements of the same class name with selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

Title may be a bit wordy. Basically I'm trying to parse the "Markings" table from this page: https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/border-collie/ with a python script leveraging a selenium headless browser. I either end up with the "Colors" table declared earlier on the page or an empty array. My current code is below for reference

```
    # get coat color
    tab = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="colors-header"]').click()
    resp = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('breed-standard__table')
    coat_colors = []
    colors = []
    coat_colors = (resp[0].text).split('\n')

    # get markings
    resp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="markings-t-h"]/tbody/tr[1]')
    for item in resp:
        print(item.text) // returns nothing
    markings = []
    #markings.append(item.text) // goal is to have the markings in an array by this pt
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the locator and click before taking values : (This is without headless to see the flow)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

PATH = r"Path to\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/border-collie/")
sleep(30)
# click the expand icon for marking table
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "markings-header"))).click()
# Print the entire table
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "accordion-markings"))).text)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
DESCRIPTION STANDARD MARKING REGISTRATION CODE
White Markings 014
Merle Markings 035
Tan Points 029
White Markings, Tan Points 030
White Markings, Ticked 439
White Mkngs, Tan Pts, Ticked 440
White Markings, Brindle Points 441
White Mkng, Brindle Pt, Ticked 442
```

With headless:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = True
PATH = r"your chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chromeOptions)

driver.get("https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/border-collie/")
sleep(30)
# click the expand icon for marking table
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "markings-header"))).click()
# Print the entire table
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "accordion-markings"))).text)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
DESCRIPTION STANDARD MARKING REGISTRATION CODE
White Markings 014
Merle Markings 035
Tan Points 029
White Markings, Tan Points 030
White Markings, Ticked 439
White Mkngs, Tan Pts, Ticked 440
White Markings, Brindle Points 441
White Mkng, Brindle Pt, Ticked 442
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried out the solution but I'm tunning into a ElementClickInterceptedException. For some reason I've been running into these a lot with this site. Here's the rest of the output: 
Message: element click intercepted: Element <div id="markings-header" class="breed-table__table-header flex flex-middle py2 ">...</div> is not clickable at point (400, 552). Other element would receive the click @QualityMatters

Comment: The exception means the page is not loaded properly. I have put some hard code wait and increased explicit wait. Can you copy the code again and run now? If it works, it means, pageloads slow in your machine, because the same code works fine in my machine  with my network.

Comment: Apologies for the late response kind stranger. It runs like a charm. I, like you just ended up increasing the wait value